# How to trigger code when target cell is filled with calculated value?

Tags: excel, vba

This works when I manually enter the value for "b37" but when I put "=c20", for example, into "b37" nothing happens.

How do I make this work for when the value in the cell referenced, "c20" changes instead of manually entering a value for "b37"?

```vb
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal target As Range)
    If Intersect(target, Range("b37")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If IsNumeric(target.Value) Then
        If target.Value < 0.95 Then
            ActiveSheet.Shapes("Straight Connector 1").Line.ForeColor.RGB = vbRed
        ElseIf target.Value >= 0.95 And target.Value < 1 Then
            ActiveSheet.Shapes("Straight Connector 1").Line.ForeColor.RGB = vbGreen
        Else
            ActiveSheet.Shapes("Straight Connector 1").Line.ForeColor.RGB = vbYellow
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    SetLineColor1 Me.Range("B37"), Me.Shapes("Line 1")
    SetLineColor2 Me.Range("D35"), Me.Shapes("Line 2")
End Sub

Sub SetLineColor1(c As Range, ln As Shape)
    Dim v, clr As Long

    v = c.Value
    If Not IsNumeric(v) Or Len(v) = 0 Then Exit Sub

    If v < 0.95 Then
        clr = vbRed
    ElseIf v >= 0.95 And v < 1 Then
        clr = vbGreen
    Else
        clr = vbYellow
    End If
    ln.Line.ForeColor.RGB = clr
End Sub
Sub SetLineColor2(c As Range, ln As Shape)
    Dim v, clr As Long

    v = c.Value
    If Not IsNumeric(v) Or Len(v) = 0 Then Exit Sub

    If v < 88 Then
        clr = vbRed
    ElseIf v >= 88 And v < 100 Then
        clr = vbGreen
    Else
        clr = vbYellow
    End If
    ln.Line.ForeColor.RGB = clr
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to react to a calculation and not a manually-entered value then you can use the `worksheet_calculate` event.

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    Dim v, clr As Long

    v = Me.Range("B37").value
    If not isnumeric(v) or len(v) = 0 then exit sub

    If v < 0.95 Then
        clr = vbRed
    ElseIf v >= 0.95 And v < 1 Then
        clr = vbGreen
    Else
        clr = vbYellow
    End If
    Me.Shapes("Straight Connector 1").Line.ForeColor.RGB = clr
End Sub
```

EDIT: if you have multiple cells to check, you could factor out the logic into a separate sub and call it for each pair of cell+shape.

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    SetLineColor Me.Range("B37"), Me.Shapes("Straight Connector 1")
    SetLineColor Me.Range("B40"), Me.Shapes("Straight Connector 8")
End Sub

Sub SetLineColor(c As Range, ln As Shape)
    Dim v, clr As Long

    v = c.value
    If not isnumeric(v) or len(v) = 0 then exit sub

    If v < 0.95 Then
        clr = vbRed
    ElseIf v >= 0.95 And v < 1 Then
        clr = vbGreen
    Else
        clr = vbYellow
    End If
    ln.Line.ForeColor.RGB = clr
End Sub
```

Comment: How would I stack this up to change other lines based on other cell values?

Comment: Thank you for your help with this!

Comment: This is great but i need to set different conditions for other shape colors, like `If v <88 Then
        clr = vbRed
    ElseIf v >= 88 And v < 100 Then
        clr = vbGreen
    Else
        clr = vbYellow`

Comment: If there are always 3 breakpoints then you can add 3 parameters (eg. limitA, limitB, limitC) pass them in as 3 additional argument.  Or make a table on another sheet with all of the rules and run over that to get the values, instead of hard-coding them in your VBA.